# API to check maximum value of any data type exceeded

Tags: c, linux, types

Is there any API to check if any number exceeds it's range?

My number is stored as string. `char *ptr = "123456789"`

API should do: `int a = api(ptr, long)` if a==-1 suppose value exceeds.

Please note: We can't parse the string and check because it will automatically wrap it to the other side, and make it within the range.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't use [signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please checkout [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) and [strtoul](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul).

See this example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    char a[] = "123";
    char c[] = "123134123412341234";
    long b, d;
    errno = 0;
    b = strtol(a, NULL, 10);
    if((b == LONG_MAX || b == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE ){
        printf("%s Out of range\n", a);
    }
    errno = 0;
    d = strtol(c, NULL, 10);
    if((d == LONG_MAX || d == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE ){
        printf("%s Out of range\n", c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edits:

1. Changed `int` to `long` for `b` and `d`.
2. Setting `errno` to `0` before calling into c library.
3. Checking for `LONG_MIN` also for errors.
4. Changed the order for checks (according to comment below)

Comment: you need to set errno to 0 before calling strtol as if it doesn't fail it may leave errno to its previous value. Formally, you also need to check that strtol result is LONG_MIN or LONG_MAX before checking errno.

Comment: You should reverse the left and right hand sides of the `&&`. Comparing `b==LONG_MAX` is trivial, but accessing `errno` is likely a mildly expensive operation, so take advantage of the short-circuit. Also you **must** set `errno=0` before calling `strtol` if you want to check for errors; otherwise, `errno` may simply be leftover from some previous function's error when the number converted really is `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: Shouldn't `b` and `d` be of type long?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can still check. Just build up the number and check to see if the number indeed became bigger or smaller.

```
int i = 0; // pos indicator
int r = 0; // result
int c = 0; // check
while(ptr[i])
{
    c = r;
    r = r * 10 + (ptr[i++] - '0');
    if(r < c)
        print("overflow happened!\n");
}
```

Edit: Note that this won't work with unsigned datatypes as it's too easy to overflow far enough to still pass the check.

Comment: I did not understand, can you please help me with the snippet. Where are you checking if it has exceeded or not?

Comment: In the `if()` statement - just ensure you use the same type for the check value. Let's assume we're using signed char (replace `int` with `char` in the example), so the maximum value would be 127. We're parsing the string "128". The first loop `c` is 0, `r` will be 1. Next run the `c` will be 1, `r` will be 12 - everything still fine. But in the third loop `c` will be 12 and `r` is now -128 (due to the overflow happening) - the if statement will be true.

Answer (score 1):

Just use strol() or strtoll() and check errno. For smaller datatypes you need to make a very simple function that compares against USHRT_MAX, UINT_MAX etc from limits.h.

man strol and man limits.h for more information.

Comment: You also have to clear `errno` in advance and check it afterwards.